# int cannot be converted to short

Tags: java

I got problem on the second public with the lambda function. Problem is int to short. It's a compiler problem.

```
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Picnicker {
    public Function<Short, Short> rechafe(Function<Short, Short> sinkstone) {
        Function<Short, Short> div = (value) -> value / 49;
        Function<Short, Short> f = sinkstone.andThen(div);

        return f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, `49` is an int literal. Thus, you have an expression `a / b` where `a` is short (it's the `value` in your `value -> value / 49;`), and `b` is an int (it's the `49`). Java silently converts your `value` to an int first, then does int/int division (java cannot do hybrid math operations). In general shorts aren't an actual thing in java, at the runtime level, it's all converted to ints/longs.

The easy fix is to cast the end result to a short. `value -> (short) (value / 49)` for example.